# Why my version of case insensitive Lucene keyword analyzer is not working

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to index documents for case insensitive search using KeywordTokenizer.

I have created a custom Analyzer that is supposed to do keyword tokenisation as well as convert all keywords to lowercase:

```
public class LowercasingKeywordAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

   @Override
   protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
      KeywordTokenizer keywordTokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer();
      return new TokenStreamComponents(keywordTokenizer, new LowerCaseFilter(keywordTokenizer));
   }
}
```

Why does search return no results when I am submitting TermQuery with all criteria terms lowecased?? Here is a unit test reproducing the issue:

```
@Test
public void experiment() throws IOException, ParseException {
   Analyzer analyzer = new LowercasingKeywordAnalyzer();

   Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
   IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
   IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);

   Document doc = new Document();
   String text = "This is the text to be indexed.";
   doc.add(new StringField("fieldname", text, Store.NO));

   iwriter.addDocument(doc);
   iwriter.close();

   // Now search the index:
   DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
   IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);

   //THE TEST PASSES WITH THE CASE SENSITIVE QUERY TERM, BUT DOES NOT PASS WITH LOWERCASED
   //Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("fieldname", "This is the text to be indexed."));
   Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("fieldname", "This is the text to be indexed.".toLowerCase()));


   ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
   assertEquals(1, hits.length);

   ireader.close();
   directory.close();
}
```

Please help me to identify what is wrong here?

NOTE: I am aware of Lucene QueryParsers as well as deprecation of some interfaces, please do not bother commenting on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StringField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) is not analyzed.  No analyzer you define will affect it.  You can use a `TextField` instead, or a `Field` where you can define your own `FieldType`.  Or just lowercase it before constructing the field and continue to use `StringField`.